# String recursion in Rust

Tags: string, recursion, rust

In Rust, I am trying to obtain all possible combinations of a-z characters up to a fixed length with no repeating letters.

For example, for a limited set of a-f and a length of 3 I should get:

abc
abd
abe
abf
acb
acd
ace
acf
adb
... etc

I've been struggling to do this through recursion and have been banging my head on ownership and borrows. The only way I've managed to do it is as follows, but this is cloning strings all over the place and is very inefficient. There are probably standard permutation/combination functions for this in the standard library, I don't know, but I'm interested in understanding how this can be done manually.

```
fn main() {
    run(&String::new());
}

fn run(target: &String) {
    for a in 97..123 { // ASCII a..z
        if !target.contains(char::from(a)) {
            let next = target.clone() + char::from(a).to_string().as_str(); // Working but terrible
            if next.len() == 3 { // Required string size
                println!("{}", next);
            } else {
                run(&next);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *"call another function on that string which returns an integer"* - Details?

Comment: A bit too long to explain in detail but it's just a function that takes a reference to a string and returns a `i32` which is based upon the string content. The `i32` can vary depending on the string and I'd like to find its maximum value.

Comment: Let's move the *"call another function"* part to another question. It's customary on StackOverflow to ask one question per post.

Comment: OK, edited to remove the second part of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, a couple of remarks:

- `&String` is kind of an anti-pattern that is rarely seen. It serves no purpose; all the functionality that `String` has over `str` requires mutability. So it should either be `&mut String` or `&str`.
- `97..123` is uncommon ... use `'a'..='z'`.

Now to the actual problem:

As long as you pass a non-mutable string into the recursion, you won't get around cloning the data. I'd make the string mutable, then you can simply append and remove single characters from it.

Like this:

```rust
fn main() {
    run(&mut String::new());
}

fn run(target: &mut String) {
    for a in 'a'..='z' {
        if !target.contains(a) {
            target.push(a);
            if target.len() == 3 {
                // Required string size
                println!("{}", target);
            } else {
                run(target);
            }
            target.pop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried that approach before but put `target.pop()` in the wrong place :) Thanks for the helpful remarks as well. Should I post another question concerning handling returns when passing `target` to another function with a link to this post?

Comment: Just open a new question with a problem description, what you tried, and why you are struggling.

Comment: No need, I applied your suggestion on using `&mut String` to a `&mut i32` which i pass around in the recursion and finding the maximum value is a no-brainer. Thanks a whole lot for your help.

Comment: Since running through all permutations for a 7-letter string is a very long process, I'm wondering if there's a way to launch the recursion process with a "start" string. After 20 minutes (single thread) with a release compile I'm getting results for the string `abelrst` (still starting with 'a'). Is there a way to specify this string as a start value if the machine crashes?

Comment: There are many ways, although all of them are off-topic for this question. Try to implement it yourself, and if you hit a specific problem that you don't know how to deal with, open a new question describing it, what you tried, and why you are struggling :) Learning how to problem-solve is the #1 most important skill for programmers, everything else like languages and mechanisms are way less important. So I always encourage to have a good go at a problem before asking for help.

Comment: I agree, this is why I was trying to solve this recursion issue without relying on external crates. It's just a self-made, completely non professional puzzle. Passing a start string to a a..z for loop seemed like a crazy idea, though, but I'll try. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Isn't super crazy, but isn't straight forward either. Good luck :) One idea would be to check if the last item of the current `run` function would be still before the checkpoint, and if yes, return from the function. That should skip to the checkpoint within only a couple of iterations.

Answer (score 0):

Just for comprehensiveness, here is an alternate way to do it, when **not** using recursion. It does use [`.permutations()`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.permutations) from crate [`Itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/latest/itertools/index.html).

Also, It's probably cleaner to return the `String` object from the function directly, instead of passing a mutable reference by argument.

```
use std::ops::RangeInclusive;
use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    println!("result: {}",combine('a'..='d', 3));
    println!("result: {}",combine('a'..='g', 4));
    println!("result: {}",combine('a'..='c', 3));
    println!("result: {}",combine('a'..='c', 4)); // assertion fail
}

fn combine(range: RangeInclusive<char>, depth: usize) -> String
{
    assert!( *range.end() as usize - *range.start() as usize + 1 >= depth);

    let perms = range.permutations(depth);
    let mut result = String::new();

    perms.for_each(|mut item| {
        item.push(' ');
        result += &item.into_iter().collect::<String>();
    });
    result.pop(); // pop last superfluous space char
    result
}
```

Comment: While this is a good solution imo, OP explicitely asked for solutions that are without `.permutations()`.

Comment: @Finomnis, my bad, I overlooked that part of the question. edited the answer a bit.